# Converting string MM/DD/YYYY to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

In my app i'm using Facebook Graph API and when I'm fetching user details i get the user's birthday as a string with format MM/DD/YYYY.

My question is, how can I convert string "MM/DD/YYYY" to `NSDate`?

I try doing

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"08/08/2012"];
 [dateFormatter release];
```

But I got the wrong date

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can convert directly from a `NSString` to a `NSDate`. Here's an example:

```
NSDateFormatter* myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate* myDate = [myFormatter dateFromString:@"8/26/2012"];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

See [Unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) for details on date formatting patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Add `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]]`

Answer (score 3):

You are doing everything fine. Your problem is only the format string.

- Capital `M` is month.
- Small `d` is day.
- Small `y` is year.

Just use these symbols consistently and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly such cases `NSDateFormatter` [exist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: This isn't really an answer, as the original question referenced NSDateFormatter.

Comment: It was not when I gave this answer. It was edited after.

Comment: @Matthias I read the question before edit.. hahaha what a twist to the question :D your answer is perfectly correct according to that question so +1 from my side for you.